# How to add an interval tier to TextGrid(silences)

Tags: praat

I would like to ask a very introductory question. I made a textgrid object in Praat using "To TextGrid (silences)." I have selected the sound and the text grid, and pressed "view and edit." Here, I can see just one tier, which shows silence and sounding part. I would like to add to another tier to annotate segmental information. To do so, I have pressed "add interval tier" button in the editor. In this case, I can successfully make another tier. To automate this process, I would like to write a script for this process. Currently, I opened a new script window and pasted the history to the window. The following is the history:

```
Read from file: "/Users/gen/Desktop/praat/0705/0705.WAV"
Convert to mono
selectObject: "Sound 0705_mono"
To TextGrid (silences): 100, 0, -25, 0.1, 0.1, "silent", "sounding"
selectObject: "Sound 0705_mono"
plusObject: "TextGrid 0705_mono"
View & Edit
Add interval tier: 2, "word"
```

I have just run this code. However, an error takes place in line 8. Praat said 'Command "Add interval tier:" not available.'

How can I add the interval tier in the textgrid?

Comment: You're getting this error message, I think, because you have a Sound object and TextGrid object selected, and you can only use the `Add interval tier:` when a TextGrid is selected

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this: 

Read from file: "/Users/gen/Desktop/praat/0705/0705.WAV"
Convert to mono
selectObject: "Sound 0705_mono"
To TextGrid (silences): 100, 0, -25, 0.1, 0.1, "silent", "sounding"
Insert interval tier: 2, "word"
selectObject: "Sound 0705_mono"
plusObject: "TextGrid 0705_mono"
View & Edit
```